# How to read wsdl from a url using java

Tags: java, http, wsdl

I'm new to java. I want to read wsdl from java. I have sample northwind service http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata

I want to read output xml for the above URL. I tried in different ways, It didn't work.

```
    URL oracle = new URL("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
```

Method #2

```
private static void readHttp() {
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
    Path file = Paths.get("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata");
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, charset)) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to proceed on this.

Thanks,

Comment: "I tried in different ways, It didn't work". Could you post the code related to those "ways", or at least the "way" you think was closest? Otherwise, it is not really clear what you are trying to do at all.

Comment: judging by your rep point , you should know by now  that `I tried in different ways, It didn't work.`  won't help

Answer (score 1):

Use `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`

```
IOUtils.toString(new URL("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/"));
```

Comment: Thank you, but my requirement is to read metadata and parse it according.

Comment: For me I used `IOUtils.toString(new URL("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/").openStream());` - so thanks for the hint